# am working on a function that return a alphabet with some letters out of it but it didnt work i dont know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i am a litte bit confused here please help. i am writing a program but the code i use suppose to work but it didnt. here it is

```
enter code here
'''
getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
  yet been guessed.
'''
import string
alph=string.ascii_lowercase
for i in lettersGuessed:
    if i in alph:
        alph.replace(i, "")
return alph
```

lettersGuessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
print(getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed)

here is another code i got from the net, it worked fine but mine nah

```
enter code heredef getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
'''
lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
  yet been guessed.
'''
import string
alph=string.ascii_lowercase
remain=[]
for i in alph:
    if i not in lettersGuessed:
        remain.append(i)
return ''.join(remain)
```

lettersGuessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
print(getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))

Comment: Can you explain what do you expect after this code?

Answer (score 0):

alph=alph.replace(i,"")
replace method returns a copy of the string where all occurrences of a substring are replaced with another substring.